# How to set colorcolumn when to run solarized.vim?

Tags: vim, colors

Here is my `set cc=5` in industry color setting.

[image]

Now solarized.vim installed to protect eyesight, the red vertical line can't created any more.
To set `hi cc guibg=red` and then `set cc=5`
No red vertical line created.

It take no effect in such .bashrc file as below.

```
syntax enable
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=160 guibg=#D80000
```

or that way

```
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=160 guibg=#D80000
syntax enable
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

None of them written in my .bashrc take effect.

[image]

Comment: Create file `~/.vimrc` and put your Vim settings inside. The `~/.bashrc` is a file to setup your Bash shell and you should not put Vim settings inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how do you setup your Vim instance, but if you change the theme manually (inside vim by command `colorscheme`), **each change of colorscheme inside editor may (or will) override default values for many visual elements** (included `colorcolumn`).

So after each change of theme try then:

```
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=160 guibg=#D80000
```

Or add this to your `.vimrc` file with line for [setup solarized theme](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized) before.